# Is there way I can find the available VM SKU's at a subscription level

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I want to know if there is any way where I can pull the vm sizes that are available for my subscription.

### I referred to the below article and command to pull the output.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azcomputeresourcesku?view=azps-3.8.0

I selected a subsctiption and then ran the below command to get the available vm sizes.
"Get-AzComputeResourceSku | Where-Object {$*.Locations.Contains("northeurope") -and $*.Restrictions.ReasonCode -ne 'NotAvailableForSubscription'}"

The output of above command is good, its giving me vm sizes which are available and not available at a subscription level. The problem is the output shows some VM skus are not available at subscription but I can able to create vm where it shows vm skus is not available.

I need help to get the vm sizes available to a subscription which are currently active and which are actually available for deployment and which are really not available for the subscription..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a similar Powershell cmdlet, but I would use this through the Azure CLI:

```
az vm list-sizes --location "your region"
```

This by default only gives you the vms available in the current subscription. If you want other info, you can also use az vm list-sku instead.

Comment: yeah, this also give the same output, A small example i want to give about the output.

I am getting the output where Standard_A1 or Standard_A2 vm sizes as not available, but from portal I can able to create the VM using the same size.


I am trying to pull all the available sizes which are actually available and which are really not available at a region for a subscription.

Comment: for what sort of subscription and region are you trying this? I see no discrepancy between the portal and azcli/powershell in for instance West Europe

Comment: I am using for a normal subscription which is purchased. In the above comments, I explained about my issue. 

I could see the difference in the output of powershell/Azcli with actually what is available in the portal

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late to help you now, but I will try answering this anyways.

The command provided above by discondor will show all possible sizes, without any consideration for subscription.

Use this instead (for Powershell module):

`Get-AzComputeResourceSku | Where-Object { $_.Locations -contains "australiacentral" }`

OR (for cloud shell bash):

`az vm list-skus --location australiacentral --all --output table`

Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-sku-not-available?tabs=azure-powershell